# How to remove XML declaration from web request

Tags: .net, soap, httpwebrequest

We're trying to talk to a web server (possibly JBoss) but it is choking on the request generated by .NET.  If we manually create the SOAP, it works, but we do not want to do that -- we would have to do it for every method in the WSDL.  The only real difference is the presence of the XML declaration.  The trouble is, I cannot figure out how to get rid of that. I'm not able to modify the request stream. Can anyone offer some advice?

```
public partial class CustomClient : GeneratedClient
{
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
  var webRequest = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
  webRequest.Method = "POST";
  var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
  // Next line cannot execute -- Stream is not readable.
  var soapEnvelope = new StreamReader(requestStream).ReadToEnd();
```

**GOOD REQUEST (manually created):**

```
POST https://remotewebserver.org/productname/service HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic BIGLONGBASE64
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: remotewebserver.org
Content-Length: 378
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:QueryLimitRequest>
            <username>email@address.com</username>
            <password>PA$$W0RD</password>
        <organization>Our Company Name</organization>
         <con:requestType>QueryLimit</con:requestType>
         <con:processingType>TESTING</con:processingType>
      </con:QueryLimitRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**BAD REQUEST (automatically generated):**

```
POST https://remotewebserver.org/productname/service HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic BIGLONGBASE64
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: remotewebserver.org
Content-Length: 532
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- XML Declaration I want to remove -->
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Body>
        <QueryLimitRequest xmlns="http://namespace.remotewebserver.org">
            <username>email@address.com</username>
            <password>PA$$W0RD</password>
            <organization>Our Company Name</organization>
            <requestType>QueryLimit</requestType>
            <processingType>TESTING</processingType>
        </QueryLimitRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```